# C null terminator's throught char* correct handelling

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

This question is aimed at improving my understanding of
what I can and cannot do with pointers when allocating and freeing:

The bellow code is not meant to run, but just set up a situation for the questions bellow.

```
char *var1  = calloc(8,sizeof(char));
char **var2 = calloc(3,sizeof(char*));

var1 = "01234567";

var1[2] = '\0';
var1[5] = '\0';

//var1 = [0][1][\0][3][4][\0][6][7]

var2[0] = var1[0];
var2[1] = var1[3];
var2[2] = var1[6];

free(var1);
free(var2);
```

given the following snippet

1: is it ok to write to a location after the \0 if you know the size you allocated.

2: Can I do what I did with var2 , if it points to a block that another pointer is pointing at?

3: are the calls to free ok? or will free die due to the \0 located throughout var1.
I printed out all the variables after free, and only the ones up to the first null got freed (changed to null or other weird and normal looking characters). Is that ok?

4: Any other stuff you wish to point out that is completely wrong and should be avoided.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `var1 = "01234567";` points `var1` to a string literal (it does not copy the string into the allocated space). Maybe you meant `strcpy` here? Or are you really asking about that code?  It would improve the question to post the exact code you are asking about, not "code not meant to run".

Comment: i'll edit the question

Comment: Please do not invalidate existing answers by changing the question. Ask a new one instead.

Comment: It would probably be better to delete this question and post a new one, since there have already been answers posted.  Check that the code you are asking about compiles before posting it, as you can see from this example the detail of the code is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's just just recap what you have done here:

```
char *var1  = calloc(8,sizeof(char));
char **var2 = calloc(3,sizeof(char*));
```

So `var1` is (a pointer to) a block of 8 chars, all set to zero `\0`.
And `var2` is (a pointer to) a block of 3 pointers, all set to NULL.

So now it's the program's memory, it can do whatever it wants with it.

To answer your questions specifically ~

It's quite normal to write characters around inside your char block.  It's a common programming pattern to parse string buffers by writing a `\0` after a section of text to use everyday C string operations on it, but then point to the next character after the added `\0` and continue parsing.

`var2` is simply a bunch of char-pointers, it can point to whatever char is necessary,  it doesn't necessarily have to be at the beginning of the string.

The calls to `free()` are somewhat OK (except for the bug - see below).  It's normal for the content of free()d blocks to be overwritten when they are returned to the stack, so they often seem to have "rubbish" characters in them if printed out afterwards.

There is some issues with the assignment of `var1` ~

```
var1 = "01234567";
```

Here you are saying "var1 now points to this constant string".  Your compiler may have generated a warning about about this.  Firstly the code assigns a `const char*` to a `char*` (hard-coded strings are const, but C compilers will only warn about this [EDIT: this is true for C++, not C, see comment from n.m.]).  And secondly, the code lost all references to the block of memory that `var1` *used* to point to.  You can now never `free()` this memory - it has leaked.   However, at the end of the program, the `free()` is trying to operate on a pointer-to a block of memory (the "01234567") which was not allocated on the heap.  This is BAD.  Since you're exiting immediately, there's no ill-effects, but if this was in the middle of execution, the next allocation (or next 1000th!) could crash weirdly.  These sorts of problems are hard to debug.

Probably what you should have done here (I'm guessing your intention though) is used a string copy:

```
strncpy(var1, "01234567", 8);
```

With that operation instead of the assignment, everything is OK.  This is because the digits are stored in the memory allocated on line1.

Comment: In C, unlike in C++, string literals have type `char[N]` (but are not modifiable).

Comment: That's great thanks, could you follow up on:                                 The calls to free() are somewhat OK (except for the bug - see below). what bugs, and how could I make them go away :D

Comment: @n.m. - Good point on the `char[N]`, I've been doing too much C++ lately.

Comment: @OctaviodelSer - the bug is the code is trying to `free()` that string `"01234567"` (line 4), which was not allocated from the heap.  It's being free()d, because the code sets `var1` to point to it (overwriting the address of the block you calloc()d on line 1).  So in that one assignment, you leak the calloc()ed memory, and then (later) cause a false-free()

Answer (score 1):

Question 4 - what's wrong

You 'calloc' some memory and store a pointer to it in `var1`.  Then later you execute `var1 = "01234567"` which stores a pointer to a literal string in `var1`, thus losing the calloc'd memory. I imagine you thought you were copying a string. Use `strcpy` or similar.

Then you write zero values into what `var1` points to. Since that's a literal string, it may fail if the literal is in read-only memory. The result is undefined.

`free(var1)` is not going to go well with a pointer to a literal. Your code may fail or you may get heap corruption.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers don't work this way.

If someone wrote

```
int a = 6*9;
a = 42;
```

you would wonder why they ever bothered to initialise `a` to `6*9` in the first place — and you would be right. There's no reason to. The value returned by `*` is simply forgotten without being used. It could be never calculated in the first place and no one would know the difference. This is exactly equivalent to

```
int a = 42;
```

Now when pointers are involved, there's some kind of evil neural pathway in our brain that tries to tell us that a sequence of statements that is *exactly like* the one shown above is somehow working differently. Don't trust your brain. It isn't.

```
char *var1  = calloc(8,sizeof(char));
var1 = "01234567";
```

You would wonder why they ever bothered to initialise `var1` to `calloc(8,sizeof(char));` in the first place — and you would be right. There's no reason to. The value returned by `calloc` is simply forgotten without being used. It could be never calculated in the first place and no one would know the difference. This is exactly equivalent to

```
char* var1 = "01234567";
```

... which is a problem, because you cannot modify string literals.

What you *probably* want is

```
char *var1  = calloc(8, 1);     // note sizeof(char)==1, always
strncpy (var1, "01234567", 8);  // note not strcpy — you would need 9 bytes for it
```

or some variation of that.

Answer (score 0):

`var1 = "01234567";` is not correct because you assign a value of pointer to `const` `char` to a pointer to mutable `char` and causes a memory leak because the value of pointer to a `calloc` allocated buffer of 8 `char` stored in variable `var1` is lost. It seems like you actually intended to initialize allocated array with the value of the string literal instead (though that would require allocation of an array of 9 items). Assignment `var1[2] = '\0';` causes undefined behavior because the location `var1` points to is not mutable. `var2[0] = var1[0];` is wrong as well because you assign a value of `char` to pointer to `char`. Finally `free(var1);` will try to deallocate a pointer to buffer baking string literal, not something you allocated.

Comment: `"01234567"` is an array of non-const `char` in C. "non-modifiable" would be a more accurate terminology

Comment: @M.M since when string literals became arrays of non-const `char`?

Comment: @VTT They never were anything else in C.

Comment: That has always been the case in C. When `const` was added to the language, they did not change string literals to be `const` because it would have invalidated all the pre-existing code that does `char *a = "foo";` and so on

Comment: @M.M it would be more accurate terminology if `const` was used for "non-modifiable" stuff. Note that they did invalidate all the pre-existing code that does `char *a = "foo"` anyway because some of that code modified array assuming that it was fine.

Comment: `const` is a keyword, not "terminology"